# ReportViewer Renders/Prints Charts Incorrectly In Print Layout

Tags: wpf, reportviewer, windowsformshost

I have an rdlc file opened through a report viewer control (in a WPF application) that renders incorrectly on some machines when in print preview. On some machines the chart body is larger than the chart area and gets cut off. It is printed this way as well. On other machines, the chart is rendered and prints correctly.
All PCs are running the same .net version, have the same DPI settings, and have the same printer selected. All other content (a matrix, table etc.)  render and print correctly on both all machines. What else should I be looking for?

[Picture: Incorrect Rendering on Left, Correct on Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb6MS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues if the user had different options set in the print dialog, things like shrink to fit or not, etc.

Comment: All print settings are the same in both dialog boxes. They are also set to the same default printer.